# How can I loop through all elements of a certain type through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, each

There are some similar questions, but mine is a little bit more specific.

I have a table element with an id of "myTable" and some tr elements inside it (let's say the tr elements are 2).

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If I try to see the number of rows in the #myTable table element, by writing

```
var numberOfRows = $("#myTable tr").length;
```

I always have 1 in the numberOfRows variable.

It only works when I add a class to all the tr elements.

```
 <table id="myTable">
    <tr class="myRows">
        <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="myRows">
        <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Let's say the class is "myRows" and write the following:

```
var numberOfRows = $("#myTable .myRows").length;
```

Then, I get the right number - 2.

So, my question is how can I get the number of certain elements or loop through them if they are not distinguished by a class (like in the example above)?

Comment: What are the elements? Can you post your markup please?

Comment: `$("#myTable tr").length` should work. Otherwise, your HTML markup is invalid.

Comment: They are table and tr elements. I don't how to paste HTML here.

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant markup (same way you pasted your code)

Comment: @Julian use standard copy/paste, or put together a jsFiddle.

Comment: Your code should work fine (http://jsbin.com/dedaguvo/1/) if not, the problem probably is something else. Also if your ultimate goal is to iterate over the tr-elements just use [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/). No need to work with the length property (http://jsbin.com/wegisuwu/2/).

Comment: Are you having multiple elements with `myTable` id?

Comment: @Felix - it is not my page and it is a terrible mess here. The page doesn't even have a <!DOCTYPE> and when I tried to put one, all the other features of the page stopped working. I suppose that the problem has something to do with this. I'm just unable to cope with this awful code.

Comment: @Yoshi - the problem is that the each() function is not working correctly with the first selector too. By the way, both the length property and the each() function work correctly, when I use a selector with a class.

Comment: @AleksandrM - No, there is only one element with this id.

Comment: @Julian Still your code as posted here is correct, just check the linked demos I posted in my comment. The problem is something else. To select elements by type is probably as old as jquery itself.

Comment: `$('#myTable tr').length` works fine > http://jsfiddle.net/WLxAq/

Answer (score 1):

you can use like :

```
$('#myTable > tbody  > tr').each(function() {...code...});
```

Comment: I'd rather wait for the OP to post his HTML. What if he doesn't have `tbody`?

Comment: @asprin just donot  use tbody

Answer (score 0):

Pure JavaScript that also works in all meyor browsers

```
 var rows=document.getElementById("myTable").rows;
 for(var rowIndex=0;rowIndex<rows.lenght;rowIndex++){
        //now do everything with tr $(rows[rowIndex]).height(80)
 }
```